# How to clean \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0..... in text data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I was trying to read a text file with the following python code:

```
     with open(file, 'r') as myfile:
          data = myfile.read()
```

Got some weird characters start with \x...., what do they stand for and how to get rid of them in reading a text file?

e.g.

......   \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0 chapter 1 tuesday 1984 \xe2\x80\x9chey , jake , your mom sent me to pick you up \xe2\x80\x9d jacob robbins knew better than to accept a ride from a stranger , but when his mom\xe2\x80\x99s friend ronny was waiting for him in front of school he reluctantly got in the car \xe2\x80\x9cmy name is jacob........

Comment: Which is it, python 2 or python 3?

Comment: I hope Jacob is ok

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's UTF-8 encoded text. You open the file as UTF-8.

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
   ...
```

2.x:

```
with codecs.open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
   ...
```

[Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: `io.open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')` will work in both 2 and 3 (unless they're using 2.5 or older, in which case they have bigger problems).

Comment: Well, if I run your code I got:                                                              
u"\xa0\n \n \nNo Former Brothers \n \n \nA BoonieRats - Jake Olson Novel \n \n \nby Bill Ellingsen \n \n\n  \n\xa0\n \n \nNo Former Brothers by Bill Ellingsen \n \nCopyright \xa9 2011 by Bill Ellingsen\n \n \nPublished by Bill Ellingsen \n \nAll rights reserved\n \n \nCover design by Daniel Cosgrove \n \nCopyright \xa9 2011 by Bill Ellingsen\n \n \n

Comment: Which is exactly what you should have. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a9/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

Those are string escapes. They represent a character by its hexadecimal value. For example, `\x24` is `0x24`, which is the dollar sign.

```
>>> '\x24'
'$'
>>> chr(0x24)
'$'
```

One such escape (from the ones you provided) is `\xc2` which is `Â`, a capital A with a circumflex.

Answer (score 0):

the below code clears the issue

```
path.decode('utf-8','ignore').strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def main():
      args = parse_args()
      if args.file :
          //To clean \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0… in text data 
          file_to_read = args.file.decode('utf-8','ignore').strip() 
          f = open(file_to_read, "r+")
          text_from_file = f.read()  
      else :
          text_from_file = sys.argv[1]
```