# string encoding after importing from csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, encoding

I'm loading data into pandas dataframes from a csv file. It's in the form of a name in the first column followed by data linked to that name in the remaining columns, and different names going down in rows. The data loads perfectly, and when the dataframe is shown everything appears perfect, including special characters.

I want to be able to locate the data linked to the names by selecting a name. I've tried both

```
df[df['NAME'].isin(['John Smith'])]
```

and setting the name as the index so I can go

```
df.loc['John Smith']
```

both of which normally work fine (although if there are better methods let me know).

However the problem is neither approach works for this data set, presumably because of some sort of encoding issue. If I want this to work then the name that is to be located has to be in the form

```
df.loc[' John\xc2\xa0Smith']
```

So even though the name appears as normal when you look at the dataframe, the names are actually stored with an extra space at the start, and between the first and last names there's a \xc2\xa0 string. I have very little experience with encodings and dealing with this sort of stuff, so my question is if theres anyway to deal with this so you can either convert the names in the dataframe to a simple string format so 'John Smith' actually represents the name when you select it from the dataframe?

edit: its not just `\xc2\xa0` which is an issue, but theres a wide variety of special letters which are represented as for example `\xc3\xb1`

Comment: `'\xc2\xa0'` is a nonbreakable space. Just replace it with a normal space. `df.NAME=df.NAME.str.strip().str.replace('\xc2\xa0',' ')`.

Comment: yeah but the problem is that's just one of many of those. any name with a special character has some form of weird string in it, e.g. \xc3\xb1. seems like a non-optimal solution going through with a .replace('\whatever','whatever letter it needs to be') on the names in the data frame when there are loads of different special letters due to international names, and the list of names is subject to change as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean \xc2\xa0 \xc2\xa0..... in text data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889265/how-to-clean-xc2-xa0-xc2-xa0-in-text-data)

Comment: that thread mentions theyre string escapes and characters represented by hexadecimal value, which explains it, so thanks for that, and that a file needs to be opened with utf-8, but thats already done in my case. the names with string escapes are displayed properly, its just that the series theyre saved in in the dataframe still contain the string escapes/hexadecimal values, so if you want to select a name from the dataframe you need to include those, which is what im trying to avoid having to do

Answer (score 0):

You can actually remove these pretty quickly with regex. In the case above, you'll also have to replace multiple spaces with just one

```
import re 

re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', text)
```

Comment: Why regex? You can use `str.replace` in pandas.

Comment: i dont want to just remove them and add a space. i want to be able to select a name and the data associated with it by typing the name in as it appears in the dataframe. just removing all stringescapes/hexadecimals wouldnt solve the problem, as names with special characters would have those characters missing and i still couldnt select their row in the dataframe by typing in their name

Comment: You're removing non ascii characters with the above regex, that wouldn't affect any normal special characters such as hyphens and apostrophes.

Comment: but any name that has a e.g. "ø" or a " ç" has that letter stored as a hexadecimal. when the dataframe is displayed the letters show up the way theyre meant to, but doing a df.loc['namewithaø'] when the names are the index doesnt work, but it has to be written df.loc['namewitha\xc3\xb8'] in order to be found